How can I call a previous tab from <target>
I'm trying to open a link in the previous tab
there's 3 pages

index.html
schedule.html
player.html

when on index.html and you press the "player" button it opens on a new tab (What I want).
When I am on the player page and I click the "schedule" button I want it to use the tab with index.html and go to schedule.html.
there is a few websites that do this but I cant figure it out.

Look at window.opener

Consider <a target= (MDN) which allows you to give a name to the tab when it's opened.  Not entirely sure it helps you with being on the player page and going back, but will allow you to reuse the same tab, eg when clicking "player" on the schedule tab it will use the previously-opened player tab/window.

From the documentation, The Window interface's opener property returns a reference to the window that opened the window, either with open(), or by navigating a link with a target attribute.
In other words, if window A opens window B, B.opener returns A.
To work with this use

index.html

<body>
<h1>Index Page</h1>
<button onclick="openPlayer()">Go to Player</button>

<script>

    function openPlayer() {
        window.open('player.html', '_blank');
    }
</script>
</body>


player.html

<body>
<h1>Player Page</h1>
<button onclick="goToSchedule()">Go to Schedule</button>

<script>
    function goToSchedule() {
        // Use `opener` to access the original tab (index.html tab) for where the player page has opened.
        if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
            //go to schedule page
            window.opener.location.href = 'schedule.html';
            
        } else {
            // if the index.html page is closed
            window.location.href = 'schedule.html';
        }
    }
</script>
</body>

